# 2 Div heights Being Merged Together

Tags: css, html

I have two divs within my header - one for a nav (`.site-navitation`) bar and the other for my header image (`.side-branding`). `.site-navigation` is set to 50px high and .site-branding is set to 400px. When placed one after the other, theoretically, the .site-branding div should start 50px from the top of the screen, but for some reason, it's starting at 0,0, hiding 50px of `.site-branding` behind the `.site-navigation` div.

If anyone could help me figure out why this might be happening, it would be greatly appreciated. To see the issue in action, visit http://www.noellesnotes.com .

Here's the relevant code:

HTML

```
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'portfolio' ); ?></h1>
                    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', '_s' ); ?></a>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

            <div class="site-branding">
                <h1 class="site-title">Noelle Devoe</h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#site-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.site-branding {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.site-title {
    width: 55%;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    background-color: rgba(199,101,56, 0.6);
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove float: left in main-navigation class, this will solve your problem